# using date between in sql where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table A with origdt as a column in it. I want to pull all the records from the table based on the following conditions

if today is tuesday then Origtdt between saturdaymorning to yesterday evening
else Origtdt between yesterday morning to yesterday evening  end

Here is the query i wrote and it is giving me an error.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday' 
        THEN 
        ( 
            OrigDt BETWEEN 
                CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() - 3, 101)) 
                AND DATEADD(SS, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)))
        ) 
        ELSE 
        (
            OrigDt BETWEEN 
                CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() - 1, 101)) 
                AND DATEADD(SS, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)))
        ) 
    END
```

Error is : incorrect syntax near Between

Comment: To check, if it's Monday would you also want the data from start-of-day Saturday, or only from start-of-day Sunday?

Comment: To make it language neutral you could use `DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 3` in place of `DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday'`; that's also a very minor performance optimisation.  Admittedly it's then less obvious which day you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE OrigDt BETWEEN 

    --sod yesterday or sod Sat if today's Tues
    CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-
        --adjust offset according to today's date
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END 
    AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 

    --eod yesterday 
    AND DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: Worked your logic, am gonna use this one. Thanks a lot John.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a start you have a lot of unnecessary converts so I've stripped those out. I assumed your first convert was to remove days so that's what I've turned it into.

The below should work and you don't need to use a case:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE  
(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday' and
 OrigDt BETWEEN DateAdd(Day, -3, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(SS, -1, GETDATE())
) 
or 
(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) <> 'Tuesday' and
 OrigDt BETWEEN DateAdd(Day, -1, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(SS, -1, GETDATE())
)
```

Comment: that was awesome suggestion. i didnot think about that. thanks christian.

Comment: No problem at all @user28455, always happy to help :)